# DynamoDB multi tenant - partition key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, multi-tenant, acts-as-tenant, nosql

I have read in a blog that I could "make" a dynamodb table multi tenant using the tenant id as the partition key and for e.g. the sort key as the customer id.

It's sounds good, but imagine that I have a big workload for a tenant id = X, so I am going to have big workload on the same partition.

Is it better to create a hash key that is the concatenate the tenantid + customerid, so i will not have a hotspot?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, depending on your access pattern.

Whenever you want to `Get` or `Query` items from a DynamoDB table, you need to provide the exact partition-key. If you don't do that, you can only `Scan`, which is a costly operation.

If you'll mostly be interested in data at `tenant-id + customer-id>`, then it makes sense to make it partition-key. If you won't have `customer-id`, then you should keep `tenant-id` as partition-key.